# Public Access Modifier and Module Exporting for Spring Beans

Tags: java, spring

Must Spring bean classes, the classes of the objects that the Spring application context sets up, be `public` classes, *for Spring to create those objects*? Obviously, if *your* beans access other beans of yours in different packages, your beans will have to be `public` to interact with each other. My question is whether **all** your bean classes must be `public`.

As the Spring code itself is in a different package from the package you code is in, conceptually Spring is doing something that ought to require `public` access to your classes. On the other hand, Spring is using reflection to create the beans, so it probably does not *need* your classes to be `public`.

It addition to the package access types, from Java 9 we have Java Modules. Do the classes need to be public and exported from your module,  if you put them in a module?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, not all classes have to be `public`. Spring can instantiate package-private classes using reflection like you mentioned without any problems..

If a package-private bean is managed by the IoC container and used by classes in the same package it's no problem. Problems only arise when you try to wire that bean across packages. Which is quite obvious of course.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why injecting package-private beans from other modules don't work? It's not that obvious to me.

Comment: @Dcortez package-private classes can be accessed only in the same package, if you try to access in a different package your IDE itself will complain.

Answer (score 10):

I always strive to have my beans implement interfaces, and have other beans depend on the interface rather than on implementing class. To answer your question, that allows my implementing classes to have default access modifiers, which has the nice side effect that other beans cannot accidentally access them if they are in other packages.

Side note, I usually use the `@Component` family annotations on my bean implementations and let Spring use package scanning to import them.

Example:

```
 package com.example.service;

 public interface SomeService {}
```

Implementation:

```
 package com.example.service.impl;

 @Service
 class SomeServiceImpl {}
```

Other class that depends on the first interface:

```
 package com.example.other.impl;

 @Component
 class OtherServiceImpl implements OtherService {

     @Autowired
     private SomeService someService;
 }
```

Comment: "that allows my implementing classes to have default access modifiers": but you could still choose to have package-private classes, *even if* your classes do not implement a `public interface`?

Comment: Well, yes and no. From Spring's point of view, yes, it will pick up and create the beans for you. For example, you can create a `@Controller` class with package-private access, and you will get the request / response behaviour as you would expect. The problem is that that you will get a compile error long before that if your package-private class is used as a dependency in another class in some other package. However, this is how the Java Language Specification was designed and is not related to Spring.

Comment: The only good thing about having an interface here is that the interface could have fewer methods than the service so you expose only what you want to expose. Personally, I prefer composition over inheritance: have a package-private `@Service` class and a public facade that depends on this service. The facade delegates all calls to the service and exposes only what is needed outside of the package.