# No qualifying bean of type 'org.context.Databasetransactionlistener' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried to use this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.package.context")
public class ContextServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<ContextServer> applicationClass = ContextServer.class;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        ////
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer databaseTransactionContainer(ConnectionFactory cf,
            Databasetransactionlistener listener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_DATABASE_TRANSACTION);
        container.setExclusive(true);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "databasetransaction"));
        container.setMessageConverter(new SerializerMessageConverter());
        return container;
    }
}

@Component
class Databasetransactionlistener {

    public TransactionsBean databasetransaction(TransactionsBean ro) {
        TransactionsBean obj = new TransactionsBean();
        System.out.println("!!!! Performing TransactionsBean processing !!!!");
        obj.setTransaction_id(" ??? some_id: " + ro.getMerchant_id());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

But when I deploy the code I get exception:
No qualifying bean of type `'org.database.context.Databasetransactionlistener' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Full log: https://pastebin.com/L99iV9i9

Can you advice how I can solve the issue? Probably I'm missing some configuration?

Comment: Is not required to declare a bean class as public, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868637/public-access-modifier-for-spring-beans)

Comment: Which class do you refer?

Comment: The `Databasetransactionlistener` class

Comment: Is it all in one file?

Comment: Did you add the dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` in the pom.xml ?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-rest in the pom.xml? Can you please show me the POM dependency?

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I tried but no result. My POM file: https://pastebin.com/xVRTsENr

Comment: I believe you have a problem with your @CompontScan. The package you specified there doesn´t include the package the Databasetransactionlistener is located, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Your bean `Databasetransactionlistener` hasn't been register yet. 
The scan begins from the beginning of class.

Add [`DependsOn`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) for `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to make sure you class has been register first.

BTW `@SpringBootApplication` has already `@ComponentScan`.